# Passing cookies to QWebEngineView

Tags: python, python-3.x, qtwebengine, qtwidgets, qwebengineview

so I have a python code which converts url to pdf like below

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import argparse



def _fullScreenRequested(request):
    request.accept()
    loader.showFullScreen()

def main():
    url = ''
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Just an example", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("--url", help="Type url")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config = vars(args)
    url = config['url']


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    loader.setZoomFactor(1)
    layout = QPageLayout()
    layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
    layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
    loader.load(QUrl(url))
    loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(lambda *args: QApplication.exit())

    def emit_pdf(finished):
        # loader.page().printToPdf("test.pdf", pageLayout=layout)
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: loader.page().printToPdf("test.pdf", pageLayout=layout))

    loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have a cookie.txt with the content below

```
    [
    {
        "domain": "www.udemy.com",
        "expirationDate": 1714906174.734258,
        "hostOnly": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "name": "snexid",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": null,
        "secure": false,
        "session": false,
        "storeId": null,
        "value": "c6sdf99-1sdab-4sd1-86ff-2dc8sfs24511"
    }
]
```

is there a way to pass cookie.txt to `QWebEngineView` or `QtWebEngineWidgets` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok none of the suggestions woked.

But this example worked --> https://github.com/PyQt5/PyQt/blob/master/QWebEngineView/SetCookies.py

This is my full code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer, QDateTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie
import argparse
import os
import json

cookie_file = None

class Window(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cookieStore = self.page().profile().cookieStore()

    def initCookies(self, cookie_file):
        if cookie_file:
            with open("output/"+cookie_file, encoding='utf8') as f:
                cookies = json.load(f)

            for cookie in cookies:
                qcookie = QNetworkCookie()
                qcookie.setName(cookie.get('name', '').encode())
                qcookie.setValue(cookie.get('value', '').encode())
                qcookie.setDomain(cookie.get('domain', ''))
                qcookie.setPath(cookie.get('path', ''))
                qcookie.setExpirationDate(
                    QDateTime.fromString(str(cookie.get('expirationDate', 0)),
                                         Qt.ISODate))
                qcookie.setHttpOnly(cookie.get('httpOnly', False))
                qcookie.setSecure(cookie.get('secure', False))
                self.cookieStore.setCookie(qcookie, QUrl())


def main():
    file_name = 'ABC123.pdf'
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Just an example", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("--url", help="Type url", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--output", help="Type output pdf file name")
    parser.add_argument("--cookie", help="Type cookie file name")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config = vars(args)
    url = config['url']
    output = config['output']
    cookie = config['cookie']
    if output:
        file_name = output
    if cookie:
        cookie_file = cookie

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loader = Window()
    loader.initCookies(cookie_file)
    loader.setZoomFactor(1)
    layout = QPageLayout()
    layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
    layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
    loader.load(QUrl(url))
    loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(lambda *args: QApplication.exit())

    def emit_pdf(finished):
        directory = "/htmltopdf/output/"
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: loader.page().printToPdf(directory+file_name, pageLayout=layout))


    loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```